# Multi select Box HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a JQuery or Javascript plugin that do the functionality like demonstrated below. Clicking on add button/text will move the selected value from first box to second one. And remove button/text will do reverse of it. Is there any plugin to gain the functionality?

Note that i need both the text and the value to be moved.

[image]

Comment: google? http://css.dzone.com/news/easy-multi-select-transfer-jqu

Comment: Actually I was not getting the proper name of this. and googled it but was fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/easy-multi-select-transfer-with-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=multiple_select

Here is the [demo](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/multiple_select/multiple_select.html)